# Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Streams

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-17

We are building executable JAR from my project using springboot. basically, application is fetching the value based on keys from ETCD cluster using java client

**here is the env.**

Springboot : 3.1.5
java : 17

Maven : 3.9.0

pom.xml with all dependencies is is below

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope> 
             <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-schema</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.netbeans.external</groupId>
    <artifactId>org-eclipse-jgit</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE180</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
    <artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
    <version>15.0.1</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20230227</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>  
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>  
</dependency>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
  <groupId>io.etcd</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetcd-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.5</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The issue seems in below code . in this code , we are fetching the value of key : "admin"

```
  String cluster0 = "http://<ip>:<port>";
        ClientBuilder clientBuilder = Client.builder()
                .user(ByteSequence.from("root".getBytes()))
                .password(ByteSequence.from("pass".getBytes()))
                .endpoints(cluster0);
        Client client = clientBuilder.build();
        KV kvClient = client.getKVClient();
        
        CompletableFuture<GetResponse> getFuture = kvClient.get("admin");
        GetResponse response = getFuture.get();

         System.out.println(response.toString());
```

and the error is

```
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Streams
```

I checked the classpath and seems all fine . there is some issue with maven dependency I guess .
I deleted all plugins from maven local repository and downloaded fresh one . still issue

Please suggest

Comment: please help. Im blocked

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved by adding below dependency in Maven POM. The class mentioned in the error is present in below lib. Thanks

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>32.1.3-jre</version>
</dependency>
```